# Android change text size to xlarge, it go out of range

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, font-size

When I change the android text size to xlarge through the system, my app will go out of range. I tried to find some solutions to solve this problem which is AutoResizeTextView, but I do not find good solution for editText and something else.

What is the correct way to solve the text size changing issue, I do not want to set the text size, I want to depend on the user setting to change it and auto fit screen.

Thank you